# How do I disable the "Start audio call" shortcut in Teams?

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, microsoft-teams

Sometimes when copying text from Microsoft Teams, I'll accidentally start an audio call with a coworker, as the keyboard shortcut for copying text (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>) is similar to the shortcut for starting a call (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>).

Seeing as my coworkers don't appreciate random calls, how do I disable the audio call keyboard shortcut in Microsoft Teams?

Comment: You should upvote this: https://feedbackportal.microsoft.com/feedback/idea/8c92e4ce-6141-ec11-a81a-6045bd78d291

Answer (score 3):

You can use the free
[AutoHotkey](https://www.autohotkey.com/).

To replace in Teams the combination
<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>
by the simpler one of
<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>,
you could use a AutoHotkey script such as:

```
#if WinActive("ahk_exe Teams.exe")
^+c::Send, ^c
```

After installing AutoHotKey, put the script in a `.ahk` file and double-click
it to test. You may stop the script by right-click on the green H icon in the
traybar and choosing Exit.
To have it run on login, place it in the Startup group at
`C:\Users\USER-NAME\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup`.

Useful AutoHotkey documentation:

- [List of Keys](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/KeyList.htm)
- [Hotkeys](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/Hotkeys.htm)

Answer (score 1):

Create a new DWORD(32 bit) "NoKeyShorts" with the value of 1 under Computer\HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Office\Teams”, then restart. This only works for the desktop application on Windows.

Information from - [https://businesstechplanet.com/how-to-disable-microsoft-teams-keyboard-shortcuts/#:~:text=Unfortunately%2C%20there%20is%20no%20way,adds%20such%20options%20to%20Teams](https://businesstechplanet.com/how-to-disable-microsoft-teams-keyboard-shortcuts/#:%7E:text=Unfortunately%2C%20there%20is%20no%20way,adds%20such%20options%20to%20Teams).

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: If this solution worked before, it does not appear to work anymore, or the registry has changed. Anyone has any other suggestions?